# Method for know unregistered tokens in APNS server (using Spring Server)

Tags: java, android, ios, spring, google-cloud-messaging

successfully done push notification in android. and now deal with ios push notification.

In the case of `gcm` sever push notification, the server notify the token is unregistered or invalid etc. likewise there is any method for get in `apns` server.

please check my code for send push notification in `APNS`

```
 public void pushMessage() {
        ApnsService service = null;
        try {
            // get the certificate
            InputStream certStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("your_certificate.p12");
            service = APNS.newService().withCert(certStream, "your_cert_password").withSandboxDestination().build();
            // or
            // service = APNS.newService().withCert(certStream,
            // "your_cert_password").withProductionDestination().build();
            service.start();
             // read your user list
            List<User> userList = userDao.readUsers();
            for (User user : userList) {
                try {
                    // we had a daily update here, so we need to know how many 
                    //days the user hasn't started the app
                    // so that we get the number of updates to display it as the badge.
                    int days = (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis() - user.getLastUpdate()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
                    PayloadBuilder payloadBuilder = APNS.newPayload();
                    payloadBuilder = payloadBuilder.badge(days).alertBody("some message you want to send here");
                    // check if the message is too long (it won't be sent if it is) 
                    //and trim it if it is.
                    if (payloadBuilder.isTooLong()) {
                        payloadBuilder = payloadBuilder.shrinkBody();
                    }
                    String payload = payloadBuilder.build();
                    String token = user.getToken();
                    service.push(token, payload);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // some logging stuff
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // more logging
        } finally {
            // check if the service was successfull initialized and stop it here, if it was
            if (service != null) {
                service.stop();
            }

        }
    }
```

and i use `com.notnoop.apns` library for send `APNS` push notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to delete the devices from you list that no longer , use the following codes

```
Map<String, Date> inactiveDevices = service.getInactiveDevices();
            for (String deviceToken : inactiveDevices.keySet()) {
               // delete from table
            }
```

here `service` is the object of `ApnsService`.

```
ApnsService service;
```

Comment: Hi Ajmal, need your inputs on connecting APNS server from Java Spring... Could you please share me any beginner tutorial for that?